# Xamarin image in button oversized

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm struggling with this for a long time. I have a button in xamarin form with an image
 and the image is way too bigger than the button, how can I make the image fit or have a reasonable size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_height="wrap_content"
```

It should work for you.

Comment: seems like this is for android only. is there any cross platform solution?